# mysql Sub queries in COUNT along with GROUP BY YEAR

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, subquery

Having some trouble figuring out the best way to do this.

Here is what I'm trying to do:

```
SELECT 
YEAR(t.voucher_date) as period,
COUNT(t.id) as total_count, 
(SELECT COUNT(t2.id) FROM booking_global as t2 where t2.booking_status = 'CONFIRMED') as confirmed,
(SELECT COUNT(t3.id) FROM booking_global as t3 where t3.booking_status = 'PENDING') as pending
FROM booking_global t 
GROUP BY YEAR(t.voucher_date)
```

This produces the below result.

```
period total_count CONFIRMED PENDING
2014     4            5        3
2015     4            5        3
```

Expected Result

```
period total_count CONFIRMED PENDING
  2014     4            3        1
  2015     4            2        2
```

Here i want to get CONFIRMED / PENDING count's for respective years, rather than getting count of all statuses.

I am not sure how to use my query as a sub query and run another query on the results.

Comment: @Dhaval and John both of your answers are giving expected result, but which one is efficient and how can i convert it to codeigniter active record

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flowing should give you right rsult

```
SELECT 
YEAR(t.voucher_date) as period,
COUNT(t.id) as total_count, 
(SELECT COUNT(t2.id) FROM booking_global as t2 where t2.booking_status = 'CONFIRMED' and YEAR(t2.voucher_date) = YEAR(t.voucher_date)) as confirmed,
(SELECT COUNT(t3.id) FROM booking_global as t3 where t3.booking_status = 'PENDING'  and YEAR(t3.voucher_date) = YEAR(t.voucher_date)) as pending
FROM booking_global t 
GROUP BY YEAR(t.voucher_date)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have a subquery that calculates each `booking_status` for each year. The result of which is then joined on table `booking_global`. Example,

```
SELECT  YEAR(t.voucher_date)  voucher_date_year,
    COUNT(t.id) total_count,
    IFNULL(calc.confirmed_count, 0) confirmed_count,
    IFNULL(calc.pending_count, 0) pending_count
FROM    booking_global t
    LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT YEAR(voucher_date) voucher_date_year,
            SUM(booking_status = 'CONFIRMED') confirmed_count,
            SUM(booking_status = 'PENDING') pending_count
        FROM    booking_global
        GROUP   BY YEAR(voucher_date)
    ) calc ON calc.voucher_date_year = YEAR(t.voucher_date)
GROUP   BY YEAR(t.voucher_date)
```